# splitting file at lines containing '>' character

Tags: file, bash, split

I have a file with some lines starting with '>' and all other lines starting with some letters. I would like to cut my big file into several smaller so that the cut would always be immediately before line with '>'.

I remember once I could write something like that in bash on my own, but unfortunately I did not save the copy.

for example

```
>1
HAVE
ANIC
EDAY
>2
FOLK
SE
>3
SUNS
HINE
```

will result into 3 files, each having '>' at the first line.

Comment: use `^>` (force the `>` to only match when preceded by a start of line (`^`)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, see if it helps

```
awk '/^>/{i++};{print > (i".txt")}' yourFile
```

the generated filenames would be 1.txt, 2.txt.....

if you need the special name pattern, the awk line (after >) need to be changed.